# Search for multiple categories

Tags: php, mysql, categories

lets say i have a table like this

```
ITEM
------
id | Name           | idCat
-------------------------
1    Bridgestone A   1,5,11
2.   Velg            2,3
3.   Bridgestone B   12,4

Category
-----------
idCat  | Name      
--------------
1        Ban
2.       Velg
3.       Velg Silver
4.       Ban Luar
5.       Ban dalam
11.      Ban Special
```

And then for example i want to search Velg..
And i get only Velg because the idCat has '2' and i using LIKE '2%'

But the problem is.. when i search BAn that the idCat is 1, i get
Bridgestone A and Bridgestone B, because the Bridgestone B has idCat 12 and it will be matched if i using LIKE '1%'

My question is, how to query to perform a search that only match with "," separated..

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Why are you not direct searching inside `Category` table?

Comment: because i want to get the item details, not category name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use FIND_IN_SET

```
select * from ITEM where FIND_IN_SET('2', idCat) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET('1', idCat) > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b2d8/1)
- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

You should also be normalizing your table. It's really bad habit to store values separated by a comma in a single field.

Here's a suggested New Schema Design

**Item**

- ItemID (PK)
- ItemName

**Category**

- CategoryID (PK)
- CategoryName

**Item_category**

- ItemID (FK)
- CategoryID (FK)

Comment: +1 and thanks for the information, that there is a sql fiddle :)

Comment: this is the same with your new question `:)`